# Is the Taylor expansion of a concave function concave?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

The title pretty much says it all. I have a complicated function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is concave. I want to approximate this function using the first few terms of a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). Is the approximation also concave? Obviously, the first order approximation is concave. The second order should also be concave too since the Hessian is negative semi-definite. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The third order Taylor polynomial of $-e^{-x}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: What if we only consider the even order Taylor polynomials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "$n$th degree Taylor expansion of a concave function is concave" is true for $n=1, 2$ as you observed.

It is false for $n\ge 3$ as gammatester noted in a comment. For one thing, there are no concave polynomials of degree 3 since the second derivative, being linear, changes its sign.